# Python create datetime object from list of values

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have a list with values for datetime object:

```
values = ['2014', '08', '17', '18', '01', '05']
```

Convert it to int:
    `values = map(int, values)`

And now I need to create newdate:

```
newdate = datetime.datetime(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5])
```

Is there better way to do this?

Comment: do you only have 6 elements in your list?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yep

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
newdate = datetime.datetime(*values)
```

The `*expression` syntax in a call takes the output of `expression` as a sequence and applies each element as a separate argument.

This'll work for any sequence with a length between 3 and 8 elements, provided the first 7 are all integers and the 8th, if present, is a [`datetime.tzinfo` subclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo).

Combined with mapping to `int`:

```
values = ['2014', '08', '17', '18', '01', '05']
newdate = datetime.datetime(*map(int, values))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> values = ['2014', '08', '17', '18', '01', '05']
>>> datetime.datetime(*map(int, values))
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 17, 18, 1, 5)
```